# Log upstart event env var EXIT_SIGNAL/EXIT_STATUS

Tags: upstart

Upstart has *job* environment and *event* environment, I am faimilar with the *jobs*, and I can write `script` stanzas to log/exec. But when the process fails, there is a `stopped` event, which has some useful environment variables - like `EXIT_STATUS`/`EXIT_SIGNAL`, which I don't know if I can log!. These are not available in the `post-stop`/`pre-stop` stanzas. So, is there any other way where I can access these variables and log them?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

In another job that has the stanza `start on stopped main-job`. Then in that job the script sections will have those environment variables.

Comment: ok, I tried this too, this is what I have: `script
    logger -t ${JOB} -p local7.info "Stopped ${JOB} ${RESULT} ${PROCESS} ${EXIT_STATUS} ${EXIT_SIGNAL}"
end script`. With this, when I stop the job with `stop main-job`, I see the log with `result=ok`, but when I kill I don't even see the log, also in either case I don't see the `EXIT_STATUS/SIGNAL`!

Comment: It will only show that if it is not a normal exit signal or exit status. Otherwise, if it was killed with SIGTERM or exited with 0, then the varibale will not be set. Same with PROCESS.

Comment: I dont think I am observing that behavior, because I am `kill`ing the process with `HUP/SEGV`, but I dont see any log. At least I expect to see `Stopped` with other variables being empty (not interpolated)!

Comment: BTW, I am on `upstart 1.5`

Comment: It will not show if the job is respawned, only if it is stopped for good.

Comment: Ah! that is not clear from the upstart cookbook!(or I misread it!) :( I thought, I could  log the exit status _whenever_ it stopped and respawned!! :(